# Add Event Listener : How to Add even listener in typescript angular?

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, addeventlistener

I am working with `google-maps` and i am showing a marker on clicking the coordinates which I am fetching through database. They work fine. But now i want to show the title of place on click of the marker, but I dont know where to put the code of event listener.

Given below is my `app.component.ts`

**app.comp.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

declare var google: any;

// Islamabad Cordinates ===================================================
var myLatLng = { lat: 33.7294, lng: 73.0931 };

// Declaare Map  ==========================================================
var map;

// Markers array to push all marker ======================================
var markers = [];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductService]
})
export class AppComponent {

  //define an array of products
  products = [];

  //constructor func
  constructor(private _productService: ProductService) { }

  //after constructor func this func runs , in which we are
  // accessing the class function getproducts and objects products
  // through this.
  // => means callback in which we are dumping data in products
  //array
  ngOnInit() {
    this._productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(products => { this.products = products; console.log(this.products); })

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    setTimeout(() => {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 12
      });

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });

      markers.push(marker);
      console.log(map)

    }, 3000);
  }

  showMarker(latitude, longitude) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    // TS convert string to Int using +
    var clickedLocation = { lat: +latitude, lng: +longitude }
    console.log(clickedLocation);

    map.panTo(clickedLocation);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: clickedLocation,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
  }
}
```

Now where should I put this code ?

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    console.log('hei');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write this code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
    console.log('hei');
});
```

Directly after the

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...
```

Comment: getting this error ( Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined )

Comment: man I know how to create plunker but do not know about creating angular2 in plunker

Comment: @UsmanIqbal, please check updated answer, it was my mistake first. This will work 100% , please let me know.

Comment: worked , i dont know why it was not working in the first place when I did the same exact thing which u just posted. Anyways Thanks